# UserManager.getAllUsers() Returns Subset

Tags: google-apps-script

A call to UserManager.getAllUsers() fails to return all users, looks like it's not aware of sub-domains using google apps. It only returns users for domain.edu and not sub.domain.edu. How can I obtain all available users ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of a sub-domain in google apps.  When a google apps domain is set up using a sub-domain, it's an independent instance of Google Apps.